# Pass extra wParam/lParam parameters?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, winapi

A standard window procedure function takes this prototype:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

When a message such as `WM_MOUSEMOVE` or `WM_CHAR`, the `WndProc` function will receive the window the message originated from, and any extra parameters, which will be with msg and wParam/lParam.

What I have now is a class. Say

```
class Random
{
    public:
        void Initialize ();

    private:
        void Draw ();
        HWND hWnd;

    friend LRESULT CALLBACK RandomProc (HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
};
```

After the `hWnd` is initialized and created by `Initialize ()`, it will send messages such as `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` to `RandomProc`. Once a message is received, I would like `RandomProc` to use `Draw ()` to redraw the window of the class `Random`.

The thing is, I will have multiple `Random` variables, and each will have a window. All the windows will send their messages to `RandomProc`, and will want it to redraw the corresponding windows of the `hWnd`. I do not know which random variable sent the message based upon the hWnd parameter nor the msg/wParam/lParam, and so cannot access the appropriate `Draw ()` function and cannot redraw the correct window.

Is there a way to pass a pointer to the class of the window to the Procedure every time a message is sent or is there another way to access the Random class whose hWnd sent the message?

Comment: Messages are meant to be sent on a per-window basis. What's in your `hWnd` parameter? If you want the windows to use the same procedure, make them use the same class, or specify the procedure as the appropriate one for each Windows class you use.

Comment: In my case, the classes are sort of like "buttons". I need to declare several of them. They would all have the same procedure, as they are all the same type of "button", but I would like them to be in separate classes for easy control and declaration of the buttons. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: But it's not like each button has the same `HWND`. That's how you tell them apart usually. Is there a huge problem with `Draw` taking a `HWND`?

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a way to  tell the class from the `HWND`. I think someone has answered that already. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aren't you looking for the [`GetWindowLongPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[`SetWindowLongPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx) functions?

This function assigns/retrieves arbitrary pointer to/from the window handle. You might assign the pointer to your Random class instance to each window you create. In the `RandomProc` you just use the `GetWindowLongPtr` and cast the pointer to `Random*`.

As Chris says in a comment, use the `GWLP_USERDATA` attribute to assign the pointer.

Comment: The useful one would be `GWLP_USERDATA` to put in your own data to differentiate.